# Receiving a 429 error when trying to create a storage account during ARM deploy

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Reciving this error when trying to deploy to a recently deleted resource group.

Have left this running for 40 minutes but it never clears.

When i use a completley newly named resource group this doesnt happen.

In my ARM template I create this storage account before i try and create the serverfarm associated with it.

Any help would be very grateful,  i can also repeat this with the same resource group.

```
 OPERATION ID90AB707C6611418B
 TRACKING ID67c301c6-93a6-4372-98bf-5bfe60f7df5f
 STATUS429
 PROVISIONING STATERunning
 TIMESTAMP29/08/2018, 12:16:59
 DURATION37 seconds
 TYPEMicrosoft.Web/serverfarms
 RESOURCE ID/subscriptions/<removed>/resourceGroups/<removed>/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/<removed>
 STATUSMESSAGE{
   "Code": "Conflict",
   "Message": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Details: Id: 39c36b85-ea54-4bc0-899f-7776e15f2511, OperationName: Create, CreatedTime: 8/29/2018 8:41:20 AM, RequestId: ce52f313-8193-4e09-bfab-28892d69adb4, EntityType: 9",
   "Target": null,
   "Details": [
     {
       "Message": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Details: Id: 39c36b85-ea54-4bc0-899f-7776e15f2511, OperationName: Create, CreatedTime: 8/29/2018 8:41:20 AM, RequestId: ce52f313-8193-4e09-bfab-28892d69adb4, EntityType: 9"
     },
     {
       "Code": "Conflict"
     },
     {
       "ErrorEntity": {
         "ExtendedCode": "59205",
         "MessageTemplate": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Details: {0}",
         "Parameters": [
           "Id: 39c36b85-ea54-4bc0-899f-7776e15f2511, OperationName: Create, CreatedTime: 8/29/2018 8:41:20 AM, RequestId: ce52f313-8193-4e09-bfab-28892d69adb4, EntityType: 9"
         ],
         "Code": "Conflict",
         "Message": "Cannot modify this web hosting plan because another operation is in progress. Details: Id: 39c36b85-ea54-4bc0-899f-7776e15f2511, OperationName: Create, CreatedTime: 8/29/2018 8:41:20 AM, RequestId: ce52f313-8193-4e09-bfab-28892d69adb4, EntityType: 9"
       }
     }
   ],
   "Innererror": null
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Storage accounts can be notoriously slow to delete. Your conflict is likely caused by that resource not having been removed yet.

You should be able to see the resource group in the portal to verify that the assets still exist, or you can query the status with `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName`.

You can also [check activity logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit).

Comment: I got this error a full 18 hours after deleting the resource group, although it does appear that stuff seems to hang around in the background for differnet periods of time